# Dynamic String x Static String

Tags: c#, string

Im creating a Windows Service and I want to put a dynamic path in the code. But it only accepts static code.

This works:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Program\\Program.exe", "-socket 12345");
```

But this doesnt:

```
String path = "C:\\Program Files\\Program";  
String programName = "\\Program.exe";  
String fileLocation = path + programName;  
Process.Start(fileLocation, "-socket 12345");
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never concat paths. Use `Path.Combine` instead.

```
String path = @"C:\Program Files\Program";  
String programName = "Program.exe";  
String fileLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, programName);
Process.Start(fileLocation, "-socket 12345");
```

Comment: Just make sure to not try `"\\Program.exe"` like the OP wrote. If the second path starts with a \, it is considered rooted and returned without concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code examples result in identical calls to `Process.Start`. Whatever the problem is, it's not shown here.

Comment: Why in the first sample it finds the file and in the second it doesnt?

Comment: @Mig, because you did not post complete code. The working and non-working code are identical.